# Calculating the height of a div using line-height and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new here. :) I'm trying to give a div completely filled with text just enough height to end after the fold but without cutting off the last line. Here is what I’ve got so far:

```js
var mathHeight = ((Math.ceil(($(window).height()-($(window).width()*0.1)) / $("body").css('line-height')))*$("body").css('line-height'));

var introHeight = function(){
  $('#intro').height(mathHeight); 
};

introHeight();
```

```css
#intro {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 55em;
  margin: 10vw 0 0 10vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="intro">
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</div>
```

The div has a margin-top of 10vw. So, what I am trying to do is take the viewport height, subtract 10vw, divide by the line-height, round up and then multiply again by line-height. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not really clear what is the desired outcome any why would you even do something like that. Btw. `§('#intro').height(mathHeight);` is not using a `$` sign.

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't see that but it didn't make it work. Here is what I am trying to do: http://www.marxen.design/test/

Comment: Np, still don't know what you're after.

Comment: Well I want the big intro block filled with ////////////// to end after the fold instead of giving it a fixed height.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?